# GurobiError: Variable has not yet been added to the model

Tags: python, gurobi

during typing a code on the python shell for an optimization problem i got this error for unknown reasons `GurobiError: Variable has not yet been added to the model`and this is the part of the code:

```
from gurobipy import *
>>> m=Model("scanning")
>>> from sympy import *
>>> v=zeros(3,1)
>>> ub=zeros(3,1)
>>> lb=zeros(3,1)
>>> x=m.addVar(lb=0,ub=3,vtype='I',name='x')
>>> m.addConstr(Array([[1,2,3],[2,1,0],[2,3,1]])*x>=0,"c0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/midow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/tensor/array/ndim_array.py", line 346, in __mul__
    other = sympify(other)
  File "/Users/midow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 266, in sympify
    if a in sympy_classes:
  File "var.pxi", line 39, in gurobipy.Var.__hash__
gurobipy.GurobiError: Variable has not yet been added to the model
```

i don't know why am i getting this error despite that syntax is right i guess, i don't know if there's something missing.
i am using `Python 3.6.8`on macOS high sierra.

Comment: What Gurobi version?

Comment: It is Version 8.1.1

Comment: @GregGlockner is there no solution for this with Gurobi?

Comment: Considering the errors in your code, it's hard to tell what you want to do. You're multiplying an array by a scalar (x).

Comment: it's not a scalar it's a symbol and i can put the whole code but i only wanted to post the line where the problem is.

Comment: The immediate issue is caused by trying to mix sympy with gurobi variables.  Sympy doesn't know what to do with gurobi variables.  Sympy tries to convert the variable object to a string which triggers the "not added to model" exception.